# Display consistently the date and time output for the who command

Tags: who

If I connect via SSH to my Debian 12 Server from another Linux Server and run the **who -m** command, it displays the following:

```
test-user    pts/1        2024-01-24 11:13 (xx.xx.xx.xx)
```

But, if I connect from a Windows 11 computer, via Windows Terminal or using a third-party App to connect to the same Debian 12 Server using the same exact user and run the same **who -m** command, the date/time format display is different.

```
test-user    pts/0        Jan 24 11:15 (xx.xx.xx.xx)
```

I am running this line in the */etc/profile* to determine the IP address from the user on every login, but it doesn't work properly as the output is different and those spaces are altering the outcome.

```
myip=$(who -m | awk '{print substr($5, 2, length($5) - 2)}')
```

Is there a way to control the date/time output for the **who** command?
What could be causing this behavior?

*Update*

Running the locale command from:

From Linux:

```
$locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

From Windows 11

```
$locale

LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Just to note that this behavior doesn't seem to happen with all the Linux Servers I connect to.  It varies and it's explained in the solution below.

As I understood the root cause as per the explanation below, I opted to use the suggestions and they both work for my use case.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Parse [`$SSH_CONNECTION`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120080/108618) instead.

Comment: This is a valid workaround and seem to resolve my issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Likely locale-related. What's the output of `locale` in both  cases? Do you get a consistent output with `LC_ALL=C who -m`?

Comment: Do you get a consistent output with LC_ALL=C who -m?

Yes, I do.

E.g.

From Linux:


LC_ALL=C who -m
test-user    pts/1        Jan 24 16:42 (xx.xx.xx.xx)

From Windows 11:

LC_ALL=C who -m
test-user    pts/0        Jan 24 15:37 (xx.xx.xx.xx)

Comment: Note that in the output of `locale`, when the value is inside double quotes, that means it is *implied*. For instance, `LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"` means that you get the `en_US.UTF-8` locale for the `LC_MESSAGES` category, but the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable is actually not set, the value is derived from the value of `LANG` (no double quote for that one, so the envvar *is* set). So in the first case, only LANG is set, and in the second none is set.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the source code of the GNU implementation of `who`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/who.c?h=v9.4#n803), you see:

> ```
>   if (hard_locale (LC_TIME))
>     {
>       time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M";
>       time_format_width = 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2;
>     }
>   else
>     {
>       time_format = "%b %e %H:%M";
>       time_format_width = 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2;
>     }
> ```

The [declaration of `hard_locale()` in gnulib](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/hard-locale.h?id=463aa5e76c1ce849ee3d572d4f09f73ffb51c01e#n21) describes it as:

> ```
>  /* Return true if the specified CATEGORY of the current locale is hard, i.e.
>    different from the C or POSIX locale that has a fixed behavior.
>    CATEGORY must be one of the LC_* values, but not LC_ALL.  */
>  extern bool hard_locale (int category);
> ```

So,

- in the C/POSIX locale, you get `<EnglishMonthNameAbbreviation> <SpacePaddedDayOfTheMonth> <ZeroPaddedHour>:<ZeroPaddedMinute>`
- in other locales: a standard ISO8601-style YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM date.

The locale for the LC_TIME category is determined by the `LC_ALL` env variable, or `LC_TIME` variable if `LC_ALL` is not set or `LANG` if neither are set. If that's `C`, `POSIX` or any string for which the system has no installed locale or if all 3 variables are unset, you get the C/POSIX locale.

The `ssh` command can pass the `LANG` and `LC_*` variables across to the server and it does by default on many Unix-like systems. `sshd` on many Unix-like systems are also configured to *accept* those `LANG` and `LC_*` variables by default. Microsoft Windows is not a Unix-like system though. Even if the `ssh` client you use there passes those variables across, it's unlikely that there be some `LANG` and `LC_*` variables in the environment containing a locale name that the server supports.

That would explain why you get the `C`-like date format when `ssh`ing from Windows and the ISO8601-style one when sshing from another Unix-like machine.

To get a consistent format, you can force the locale to `C` by running `who` with:

```
LC_ALL=C who -m
```

But here, it seems you rather want to extract the part between the first occurrence of `(` in the line and the last occurrence of `)`, containing information of where the tty was logged in from, which you could do with:

```
who -m | perl -ne 'print $1 if /\((.*)\)/'
```

For ttys created by `sshd` and provided those environment variables were not cleared (like for instance by `sudo` or `su -`), you can extract the IP address of the ssh client from the `SSH_CLIENT` variable, with:

```
ipaddress="${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the suggestion above and It fixed my issue.

```
myip=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')
```

This second approach also seems to work:

```
myip=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}')
```

Thanks everyone!